# Database encryption or drive encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, windows-server-2016

I'm thinking about encrypting the database that contain sensitive user data. Is it better for performance to encrypt the entire drive by using something like bitlocker or is it better to just encrypt the database using the built-in encryption in SQL server?

I'm using SQL server 2016 on a windows server 2016 machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Transparent Data Encryption (TDE), your backups are also encrypted automatically regardless of destination.

With Bitlocker, if someone takes a backup to another location (like a network drive path or Azure), that backup isn't encrypted.

With both methods, if someone has access to run a SELECT command, you're screwed.

For more details on both, grab [Microsoft's SQL Server Compliance Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6808). It's old (circa 2008), but goes into way more detail. It's one of the best white papers I've ever read in that it maps business goals to SQL Server features.

Comment: TDE is the built-in encryption in sql server right?

Comment: Yes, correct - although only in SQL Server Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Also available in the Standard Edition of SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Purely looking at performance, bitlocker is faster, more performance.  However if your data is sensitive, your encryption type should be based on your compliance/security requirements.  As an example if backup encryption is required TDE is a better option.